# Editable text widget for GWT?

Tags: gwt, web-applications, textarea

I have an app in GWT that provides lots of little paragraphs and let's the user edit them.  Right now I just have a view mode, just an HTML paragraph, and an edit mode, for which I use a standard HTML TextArea.

Is there a fluid GWT paragraph editing widget that does not require using a TextArea or switching between modes?  Note that I do *not* need a rich text widget as I don't want bold, italic, bullet points, etc.

I would be willing to use a jQuery or other JavaScript library solution as long as it was really robust and cleanly separated from everything else I'm doing.  I don't want to babysit/hack on JavaScript.

Somehow I think this problem is hard, as Google Docs doesn't do it well and even stackoverflow has me using a very TextArea-like box to edit text that is later displayed as an HTML paragraph.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with [`RichTextArea`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/RichTextArea.html)?

Comment: @ThomasBroyer Thanks!  Whenever I had seen an example of rich text in action, it came with all of these buttons for bold, italic, etc. which I assumed were inherent to the widget.  However I just looked at this example: http://examples.roughian.com/index.htm#Widgets~RichTextArea it seems that they are not, which means it should work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use HTML ContentEditable. http://html5demos.com/contenteditable/

```
<div contenteditable="true">
</div>
```

You can use a JS framework to bind to changes. I have noticed issues with the JS 'change' event, but the 'blur' event works well.

Comment: Wow, that's amazing.  Haven't looked at the source yet.  Any gotchas?  I suppose I could provide bindings so the user could alter non-text properties such as creating a new bulleted list?

Comment: @Daniel: the big gotcha with contenteditable is security. You can always paste in formatted content, and the browser converts it to HTML. When you then send the content to a server, and later display it again in a HTML context, this allows for all kinds of XSS attacks. You would need to clean the HTML on the server, but blacklisting approaches are unreliable, and using whitelisting with contenteditable is **very** hard, because every browser generates quite different HTML code (the generated HTML gets even more complex if you edit text in one browser that was created with a different one).

Comment: I really just need text, so I can strip all the HTML.  Further, Google provides a SafeHtml library for dealing with this: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideSecuritySafeHtml